# touch and drag multiple controls in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, touch

I want to select multiple views in an interface and drag them together.
How can I implement this in xcode.

For example i have some image views in a view then i want to select them by drawing a rectangle. then move them by dragging them.

Can anybody help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
#import "TouchView.h"


//TouchView.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TouchViewDelegate.h"

@interface TouchView : UIView {
    id <TouchViewDelegate>  delegate;
}
@property (retain) id delegate;
@end

//TouchView.m

@implementation TouchView
@synthesize delegate;

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
}
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
}
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [delegate touchDown:self];
}
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [delegate touchUp:self];
}
@end

//TouchViewDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol TouchViewDelegate
-(void) touchDown:(id) sender;
-(void) touchUp:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: I want to move multiple views together